# Dates management in Pandas - np.array, timestamp, datetime, etc

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, type-conversion, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to convert a whole column (actually four columns) from object to datetime.

As I observed in dataframe, there are some NaN values which are making my life more difficult, so I took the following strategy:

1. Fill NaN values to a specific date using `df[column].fillna('2030-1-1')`
2. Convert to date time using `pd.to_datetime`

The curious thing is that this strategy worked only for two columns, while the other two the error insists, as shown in below picture.
[As you can see, the first two columns has successfully been converted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdCsZ.png)

Although all columns have received the same information from `fillna` command, the last two columns cannot be converted
[as shown in this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7Of4.png)

I also observed that these columns differ from datatype originally
[as you can see, the "error column" originally has a related `datetime.datetime` array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnbW7.png).

I have researched for NumPy `array` documentation, but I could not yet solve this problem. Would you help me?

Comment: Please post example data and code as text, not image. You'll get better answers in less time because people don't have to use OCR or type in the text from your screenshots.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is solved if you use `.fillna('2030-01-01')` instead? If you want a more consistent solution, I would instead suggest you parse dates first, and then fill nans. You can do that with `pd.to_datetime(..., errors="coerce")`, which will leave all entries it is unable to convert as `NaT` (Not a Time).

Comment: ...and on-topic, in general, you can set `errors="coerce"` keyword in pd.to_datetime, which will leave you with `NaT` in cases where an element cannot be parsed to datetime. You can later fillna those NaT elements, e.g. with pd.Timestamp("2030-01-01").

Comment: I would like to thank you all because it worked after your orientations!!